# AjaxStart showing Loading images continuously only in IE8.Not Hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Loading Images are showing continuously in IE8 but not hiding.can you help me what is the problem in this code?

```
var timeout;

$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    timeout = window.setTimeout(ShowLoading, 500);
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    HideLoading();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LoadingDiv").hide();
});

function ShowLoading() {
    $("#LoadingDiv").show();
    return false;
};

function HideLoading() {
    $("#LoadingDiv").hide();
    return false;
};
```

Comment: what do you mean by "continuously" ? as opposing to what, periodically?

Comment: @Banana Can you help me why its not stopping?

Comment: i dont understand what seems to be the problem. what exactly is not stopping? is your ajax being executed and returns successfully?

Comment: No The loading image is not hiding..

Comment: You dont need to set a time out, just call the showdiv function directly